# Is it possible to rewrite (update) a driver for an unsupported legacy interface?

Tags: windows, driver, legacy

Problem: I have an Roland Edirol UA-1000 10-Channel audio interface. It is still as good as what is out there and the last driver update for it was based upon Windows 7. It is hit/miss on Windows 10 compatibility.

What I would like to do is decrypt the driver and update it to work. I'm not sure if that is possible but this interface does much more than anything out there right now (i.e. clocking, optical, midi, coaxial, ADAT, etc.) unless you want to buy 3-4 separate pieces. The driver is just incompatible with Win10.

I have worked as a developer the past 10 years (e.g., VB.net, Java, Javascript, VBScript, SQL, Android) so I would like to try updating the driver for this interface.

Would it be possible... any suggestions outside of "buy something new?"

Comment: Possible? Sure. Possible for someone that hasn't had any exposure to C and hasn't been doing reverse engineering for a decade? Probably not.

Comment: I actually started in C but moved to Java but I agree. That's what I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on [GearSpace.com](https://gearspace.com/). My house in disarray now because we're having some work done so I can't look for my notes. My `UA-1000` DOES work with Win 10, there are drivers that work and a procedure to follow and I believe I found the info on [GearSpace.com](https://gearspace.com/). I just updated my software to REAPER and although I haven't recorded anything yet the meters on my `UA-1000` and the input show up in REAPER on my PC so don't go nuts trying to rewrite software.

The only downside to the `UA-1000` is the 8 audio in's and outs because if you want to expand to `16 ch's` using ADAT and another interface you can't record above 48Khz.

Comment: https://gearspace.com/board/electronic-music-instruments-and-electronic-music-production/1085974-roland-edirol-ua-1000-driver-windows-10-a.html?highlight=ua-1000+Win+10#post14559028

Answer (score 0):

*Possible*, but difficult. You will need to learn C or C++, a lot about Windows driver APIs, and a lot about reverse engineering. The existing driver may not be much help at all. You won't be able to extract any kind of readable code from it. You would basically be starting from scratch, with black-box observation and/or disassembly of the existing driver as *guidelines*. It would be difficult work, and the result would be something that would have limited use to other people anyway, thanks to Windows driver signing.

Comment: This is ignoring the most challenging aspect: Reverse engineering the actual hardware. Even though you can (eventually) see code writing to or reading from hardware registers it's extremely hard finding out what those registers control or what the values mean (without damaging the hardware along the way).

Answer (score 0):

I love my UA-1000 and did get it working on both Windows 10 and 11 using the Windows 7 64-bit drivers from Roland:
https://www.roland.com/global/support/by_product/ua-1000/updates_drivers/

**Note:** For Windows 11, the install will tell you that *"Memory Integrity"* security will need to be turned off.  There's no way I found to get around it.  If you need to turn it back on, uninstall the UA-1000 driver then search for the *"Core Isolation"* settings and re-enable Memory Integrity.  Basically, the old UA-1000 driver isn't built to the latest Windows driver security standards.

**Install Steps:**

1. Download Windows Vista 64-bit drivers.
2. Unzip the archive into a folder.
3. Connect the UA-1000 to the computer and turn it on.
4. Right click Start menu and search for the "Device Manager".
   The UA-1000 appears in the "Sound, video and game controllers" with a yellow triangle.
5. Right click on EDIROL UA-1000 and select "Update driver".
6. Select "Browse my computer for drivers." Point to the folder containing the drivers you unzipped in step #2.
7. Click "Next" and the drivers will be installed.

You may need to reboot.  By the way, I've written drivers for Windows and OS/2 (yeah, I'm old)  -- you don't want to do that, so enjoy the steps above.

**Note 2:** Initially, my UA-1000 was recognized but not outputting any sound.  But once I did a factory reset on the UA-1000, it sprang to life.  Resetting the UA-1000 is described on page 44 of the user manual which you can get from the same link above.  Have fun!